# Bitmap beyond the ImageView edge or seemed to be clipped when I rotate a layout which has the ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, android-animation

I have a `ViewPager` like `custom layout`, named `FrameViewPager`, you can call it rotate ViewPager . And I applied a `FragmentPagerAdapter` in a `activity`.

When i drag the page,the page did rotated, but the Bitmap of a `ImageView`,which was added in the page, seemed to be clipped.And i found a lib named `TinderSwipe`, the bitmap also changed when the layout rotating,but the bitmap was beyond the image edge, not clipped. I've tries a lot of times,but i cannot resolve this problem.how can fix this?

this is my implement.
[image]

this is `TinderSwipe` implement.[image]

Answer (score 0):

problem solved! I set the ImageView'ScaleType = "CenterCrop" cause the bitmap could not fit the ImageView's edge.When it rotate, the short boundary inside the ImageView, and long boundary outside the ImageView, so it looks like clipped.